# Conditional Subsetting based on column numbers

Tags: r, function, subset

I need to subset data for when columns don't match.  For example if I have an identifier in the first column X like 1 then all of the following examples in column Y should match:

```
X <- rep(1:4, times=2, each=2)
Y <- rep(c("Dave","Sam","Sam","Sam"))
Z <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y))
head(Z)
```

So on this one I would like to subset the data when X = 1 and 3 on this example since column y doesn't fully agree by not subset column 2.  It would be great to get a function to subset for this type of problem I have on a larger dataframe

Thanks,

Comment: `Z[Z$X %in% c(1,3),]`?

Comment: I would like to be able to do this for all of the conditions that meet this condition, this was just a small illustrative example, thanks though.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I figured it out using sqldf with the following:                                         
             `AA  <- sqldf("select X,
              count (distinct(Y)) as distinct_names
             
             From Z
             Group By X
             Having count (distinct(Y)) > 1
             Order by X")
AB <-                Z %>% inner_join(AA)

AB <- AB %>% select(X, Y)

AB  `   It is just clunky that way and want to see if it could work better

Comment: Well if it works, use it.  If you want to see a more R way to do it, without SQL, see the answer below.  Not sure which is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:4, times=2, each=2),
                 y = rep(c("Dave","Sam","Sam","Sam")))

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(any(!y == lag(y), na.rm = T))

#> Source: local data frame [8 x 2]
#> Groups: x [2]
#> 
#>       x      y
#>   <int> <fctr>
#> 1     1   Dave
#> 2     1    Sam
#> 3     3   Dave
#> 4     3    Sam
#> 5     1   Dave
#> 6     1    Sam
#> 7     3   Dave
#> 8     3    Sam
```

I tested some cases, not sure if this holds a lot of edge cases

Comment: This works, I tested it on my much larger data frame and it is equivalent, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it, though there may be a more elegant way.  Is this what you need?

```
X <- rep(1:4, times=2, each=2)
Y <- rep(c("Dave","Sam","Sam","Sam"))
Z <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y))
head(Z)

# First Create Concatenated column
Z$XY <- paste(Z$X, Z$Y)

# Eliminate all duplicates
Z_unique <- unique(Z)

# Find number of occurences of each X value
n_occur <- data.frame(table(Z_unique$X))

# Pull only those that have occurred more than once
n_occur[n_occur$Freq > 1,]

# Subset the output to only those values
output <- Z[Z$X %in% n_occur$Var1[n_occur$Freq > 1],]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[any(!y == shift(y))], x]
#   x    y
#1: 1 Dave
#2: 1  Sam
#3: 1 Dave
#4: 1  Sam
#5: 3 Dave
#6: 3  Sam
#7: 3 Dave
#8: 3  Sam
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:4, times=2, each=2),
              y = rep(c("Dave","Sam","Sam","Sam")))
```